# Thymeleaf динамическое изменение страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, thymeleaf

Делаю CRUD приложение на Spring Boot с использованием Thymeleaf.

Представление является таблицей с данными из БД.

В самом правом столбце, то бишь в конце каждой строки (записи), есть кнопка "Изменить" для изменения всей той строки, что слева от кнопки.
Так вот я хочу сделать так, чтобы по умолчанию в каждой строке отображались данные из БД, но при нажатии кнопки "Изменить" чтобы вся эта строка преобразовывалась в форму для ввода данных. То есть чтобы форма для ввода была не где-то в другом месте таблицы, а появлялась прямо на месте записи, которая будет изменяться.
Возможно ли это сделать с помощью Thymeleaf?

Я пробовал создавать Thymeleaf'овскую переменную для каждой записи и пытался менять ее значение при нажатии на кнопку "Изменить", но я так и не понял как это правильно делать.
Вот часть представления:

```
<table border="1" color="black" border-collapse="collapse">
    <tr>
        <td><b>ID</b></td>
        <td><b>Кличка</b></td>
        <td><b>Имя</b></td>
        <td><b>Пол</b></td>
        <td><b>Порода</b></td>
        <td><b>Дата рождения</b></td>
        <td><b>Щенки</b></td>
        <td><b>Добавлено</b></td>
        <td><b>Изменено</b></td>
        <td>Изменить</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form modelAttribute="dog" th:method="POST" th:object:"${dog}" th:action="@{/}" action="#">
            <td><input type="submit" value="Добавить"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.nickname}" id="dog.nickname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.name}" id="dog.name"/></td>
            <td><select th:field="*{dog.gender}" id="dog.gender">
                    <option th:each="genderType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Gender).values()}" 
                        th:value="${genderType}" th:text="${genderType.type}"></option>
                </select></td>
            <td><select th:field="*{dog.breed}" id="dog.breed">
                    <option th:each="breedType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Breed).values()}" 
                        th:value="${breedType}" th:text="${breedType.type}"></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" th:field="*{dog.dateOfBirth}" id="dog.dateOfBirth"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.puppies}" id="dog.puppies"/></td>
            <td></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="dog : ${dogs}">
            <span th:with="isModifying=${false}">
                <form th:unless="${isModifying}" modelAttribute="dog" th:method="POST" th:object:"${dog}" th:action="@{/}" action="#">
                    <td th:text="${dog.id}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${dog.nickname}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${dog.name}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${dog.gender.getType()}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${dog.breed.getType()}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${dog.dateOfBirth}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${dog.puppies}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${dog.modifiedAt}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${dog.createdAt}"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" th:with="isModifying=${true}" value="Изменить"/></td>
                    
                </form>
                <form modelAttribute="dog" th:if="${isModifying}" th:method="POST" th:object:"${dog}" th:action="@{/}" action="#">
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.id}" id="dog.id"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.nickname}" id="dog.nickname"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.name}" id="dog.name"/></td>
                        <td><select th:field="*{dog.gender}" id="dog.gender">
                                <option th:each="genderType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Gender).values()}" 
                                    th:value="${genderType}" th:text="${genderType.type}"></option>
                            </select></td>
                        <td><select th:field="*{dog.breed}" id="dog.breed">
                                <option th:each="breedType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Breed).values()}" 
                                    th:value="${breedType}" th:text="${breedType.type}"></option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="date" th:field="*{dog.dateOfBirth}" id="dog.dateOfBirth"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.puppies}" id="dog.puppies"/></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Сохранить"/></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" value="Сброс"/></td>
                        <td><input type="button" th:with="isModifying=${true}" value="Отменить"/></td>
                    </form>
       
                </span>
        
            </tr>
 </table>
```

UPD Нашел вот что https://codething.ru/ajax.php , https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/41120/ но плохо понял как это правильно прикрутить, так как в JavaScript не разбираюсь.